# Getting the order position JQuery sortable list?

Tags: jquery

How can i get the order position of Jquery sortable list?

Comment: Are you asking how to get the new position of the element you just sorted in a list?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If your elements have IDs (if they don't, pick a prefix and number them) you can use the [`toArray` method](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#method-toArray) to get the array of IDs in their current order, for example:

```
var idsInOrder = $(selector).sortable("toArray");
```

If you want to find the position of a particular one, use [`$.inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/), like this:

```
var index = $.inArray("idToLookFor", idsInOrder);
```

This will return the `0`-based index in the list the ID you're looking for is, or `-1` if it's not found.

---

More generally, if you just want to get the index of an element amongst its siblings, use [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) with no parameters, like this:

```
$("#myElem").index();
```

If your sortable was for example a `<ul>` with sortable `<li>` children, calling this on an `<li>` would also get it's `0`-based index, within it's siblings.

Comment: add a data attribute and use that instead of a id with a prefix